# How to shrink excel columns in a way that text is not hidden using Python3?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns: Parent and Methods/Children. I want to indent the two in a way that the Parents column is shrunk, Methods/Children shifts left and no textual information from Parents is lost.

This is what I have currently:
[image: current]

And this is what I am aiming to achieve:

[image: target]

As you can see, the Parent and Methods/Children column looks indented without the Parent column's values being shrunk.

I am currently using the following code, none of which is used in indents:
`df.to_excel(self.writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=True, index=False)`
And this is how I am darkening the edges:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=self.file_name)
ws = wb[sheet_name]
bd = Side(style='thick', color='000000')
```

Comment: How is Python and Pandas related?

Comment: Because I am coding in Python3.

Comment: @MohitMotwani
Thanks for asking these questions, I realized that my question was missing relevant information. I have edited it. However, you added a comment and then edited the question at the same time(w/o waiting for me to give you an answer) and that caused me a good amount of loss: no tags in the question for 9 hours. 

Open to more feedbacks.

Comment: Let me correct you by saying you wouldn't have received any help from Python and Pandas contributors because use your question was incomplete.

Comment: Either I would have been asked to clarify, downvoted or maybe some would see the tags and might have figured it out, but there would have been an audience of pandas and python contributors. That sight turning into help is something that you shouldn't have judged yourself because I have seen many questions with tags stating the platform to be used.